# Convert String To List of Dictionaries Python3

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Using Python 3.5.2, what is the best way to convert a string into a list of dictionaries?

I'm scraping a site, with the following being returned as a list of length 1:

(Formatted for readability)

```
[
{"variation_id":573,"variation_is_visible":true,"variation_is_active":true,"is_purchasable":true,"display_price":1099,"display_regular_price":1099,"attributes":{"attribute_pa_size":"king"},"image_src":"","image_link":"","image_title":"","image_alt":"","image_caption":"","image_srcset":"","image_sizes":"","price_html":"<span class=\"price\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#82;<\/span>1,099.00<\/span><\/span>","availability_html":"<p class=\"stock in-stock\">2 in stock<\/p>","sku":"6006239211693","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":2,"backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false,"is_virtual":false,"is_sold_individually":"no","variation_description":""},

{"variation_id":574,"variation_is_visible":true,"variation_is_active":true,"is_purchasable":true,"display_price":989,"display_regular_price":989,"attributes":{"attribute_pa_size":"queen"},"image_src":"","image_link":"","image_title":"","image_alt":"","image_caption":"","image_srcset":"","image_sizes":"","price_html":"<span class=\"price\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#82;<\/span>989.00<\/span><\/span>","availability_html":"<p class=\"stock in-stock\">2 in stock<\/p>","sku":"6006239211686","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":2,"backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false,"is_virtual":false,"is_sold_individually":"no","variation_description":""},

{"variation_id":575,"variation_is_visible":true,"variation_is_active":true,"is_purchasable":true,"display_price":949,"display_regular_price":949,"attributes":{"attribute_pa_size":"double"},"image_src":"","image_link":"","image_title":"","image_alt":"","image_caption":"","image_srcset":"","image_sizes":"","price_html":"<span class=\"price\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#82;<\/span>949.00<\/span><\/span>","availability_html":"<p class=\"stock in-stock\">2 in stock<\/p>","sku":"6006239211679","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":2,"backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false,"is_virtual":false,"is_sold_individually":"no","variation_description":""}

]
```

I tried converting that to a str, assigning it to 's' and then using  json.loads(s), but that didn't work.

I'd like to have a list object whereby I can access values with something like:

```
for item in form_data_returned:
    print item['variation_id']  # prints 573  574  575
```

Thanks

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(my_str)`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I think `literal_eval` will choke on lowercase `true`

Comment: Can't you just parse this as [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)? How exactly did that not work? Aha, seems to choke on some escaped `\"`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Set aliases for `true` and `false` in the output so
# we won't get NameError exceptions thrown.
true = True
false = False

raw = [
{"variation_id":573,"variation_is_visible":true,"variation_is_active":true,"is_purchasable":true,"display_price":1099,"display_regular_price":1099,"attributes":{"attribute_pa_size":"king"},"image_src":"","image_link":"","image_title":"","image_alt":"","image_caption":"","image_srcset":"","image_sizes":"","price_html":"<span class=\"price\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#82;<\/span>1,099.00<\/span><\/span>","availability_html":"<p class=\"stock in-stock\">2 in stock<\/p>","sku":"6006239211693","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":2,"backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false,"is_virtual":false,"is_sold_individually":"no","variation_description":""},

{"variation_id":574,"variation_is_visible":true,"variation_is_active":true,"is_purchasable":true,"display_price":989,"display_regular_price":989,"attributes":{"attribute_pa_size":"queen"},"image_src":"","image_link":"","image_title":"","image_alt":"","image_caption":"","image_srcset":"","image_sizes":"","price_html":"<span class=\"price\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#82;<\/span>989.00<\/span><\/span>","availability_html":"<p class=\"stock in-stock\">2 in stock<\/p>","sku":"6006239211686","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":2,"backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false,"is_virtual":false,"is_sold_individually":"no","variation_description":""},

{"variation_id":575,"variation_is_visible":true,"variation_is_active":true,"is_purchasable":true,"display_price":949,"display_regular_price":949,"attributes":{"attribute_pa_size":"double"},"image_src":"","image_link":"","image_title":"","image_alt":"","image_caption":"","image_srcset":"","image_sizes":"","price_html":"<span class=\"price\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#82;<\/span>949.00<\/span><\/span>","availability_html":"<p class=\"stock in-stock\">2 in stock<\/p>","sku":"6006239211679","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":2,"backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false,"is_virtual":false,"is_sold_individually":"no","variation_description":""}

]

# keys being a set ensures that every key occurs only once.
keys = set()

# Initializing form_data_returned as a defaultdict allows
# us to access keys that are not already in form_data_returned.
# For example form_data_returned['weight'].append('kg') would throw
# KeyError exception for an empty form_data_returned had we declared
# it as a normal dict().
form_data_returned = defaultdict(list)

for dictionary in raw:
    keys.update(dictionary.keys())
    for key in keys:
        form_data_returned[key].append(dictionary[key])
```

We can now retrieve data by key:

```
print(form_data_returned['variation_id'])
>>> [573, 574, 575]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module to preprocess the string, then use the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module to parse it into a dictionary.

Assuming you have the data converted to a string, and you are know that certain rules apply to the content*, you can try the following:

```
str = '...'

escaped = re.sub('(?<=[^,:{}])(\\\")(?=[^,:{}])','\\"',str)

dict = json.loads(escaped)
```

The regular expression `(?<=[^,:{}])(\\\")(?=[^,:{}])` will parse the string and identify all characters `"` that are not preceded by `',' , ':' , '{', '}'` or followed by the same, so that the `"` in the strings in the data can be escaped properly.

*by rules i mean, that you have to know, that the used regular expression finds the correct characters - if the data source can provide that consistency, the code above should work (extend the `(?<=[^,:{}])` and `(?=[^,:{}])` parts with the necessary characters to match all data